# Yo-yo effect on animation don't work when repeat is indefinite and direction is alternate using A-frame

Tags: aframe

I'll make some indefinite animations inside my A-frame web application. My animation must play infinity and must have a yo-yo effect. Form an opacity of 0.25 to 0.75 an back each in 3000 millisecondes. For this I use next code:

```js
let box = document.createElement('a-box');
box.setAttribute('src', '#outer');
box.setAttribute('position', '0 0 -5');
box.setAttribute('color', 'red');

let anim = document.createElement('a-animation');
anim.setAttribute('attribute', 'opacity');
anim.setAttribute('from', '0.25');
anim.setAttribute('to', '0.75');
anim.setAttribute('fill', 'both');
anim.setAttribute('repeat', 'indefinite');
anim.setAttribute('dur', '3000');
anim.setAttribute('direction', 'alternate');
box.appendChild(anim);

document.getElementsByTagName('a-scene')[0].appendChild(box);
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<a-scene></a-scene>
```

Like you can see this is not working. It goes from 0.25 to 0.75 in 3000 millisecondes and instantly back to 0.25 to repeat again. In the [documentation of A-frame](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/animations.html#direction) stand this:

> When we define an alternating direction, the animation will go back and forth between the `from` and `to` values like a yo-yo. Alternating directions only take affect when we repeat the animation.

If I use an number *(example the number `x`)* instead of indefinite, the yo-yo effect works great but stops when it's `x`-times repeated.

What could I do for fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's fixed by throwing out the fill attribute

```
anim.setAttribute('fill', 'both');
```

Its supposed to handle the animation when its not playing, i guess when the replay is indefinite, its playing all the time and either tween.js or three.js don't like it.

Working demo based on Your code:
https://codepen.io/gftruj/pen/qjdZmw

I tried setting it to 'none' or whatever, but i only got it working while thrown out.